# OnChange Handler ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component which i am importing into my `App.js` file and trying to set the value and an `onChange` method which i am passing down as props but not sure why that isn't working. Here is what the structure looks like:-

This is my app.js file:-

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Nested from './Nested.js'

class App extends Component {
   state = {
     childState: {
        title: 'New Title',
    }
 }

updateTitle = (e) => {
   const rows = [...this.state.childState];
   rows.title = e.target.value
     this.setState({
       rows,
  });
}


render() {
   return (
     <div className="App">
      <Nested
       title = { this.state.childState.title }
       updateTitle = {this.updateTitle.bind(this) } />
    </div>
   );
 }
}

export default App;
```

And this is my Nested Component:-

```
import React from 'react'

const Nested = (props) => {
    return (
       <div>
          <input value = { props.title } onChange = { props.updateTitle }></input>
      </div>
    )
 }

export default Nested;
```

If someone can point out what i am doing wrong in the above `updateTitle`, i'll appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: What should be in place of that instead?

Comment: Can you please clarify what is purpose of `rows` and where you are using this?

Comment: It's just a const that stores a copy of the state so the state is never mutated directly.

Comment: `updateTitle = (e) => {
   const rows = this.state.childState;
   rows.title = e.target.value
     this.setState({
       childState: rows
  });
}`

Comment: @aleemmd You should never mutate state directly. Here you are mutating `rows` which points to `childState`. See my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First mistake you making is that `this.state.childState` is an object and you spreading it inside `[]`. You should use `{}`

Secondly you don't need to set `rows` as property in your state. You should use the same name which is `childState` instead of rows

```
updateTitle = (e) => {
   const childState = {...this.state.childState};
   childState.title = e.target.value
     this.setState({
       childState,
  });
}
```

Comment: ohh i see now.  thank you for the help. Accepting this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
updateTitle = (e) => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    childState: {
      title: e.target.value,
    },
  }));
}
```